# Makefile keeps messing up BASH variables

Tags: macos, bash, makefile

If I use this code in my Makefile it keeps messing up on line 3. Here is my code:

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=512 count=2880 of=testfloppy.img
device=$$(hdid -nomount testfloppy.img)
echo $device
newfs_msdos -F 12 $device
hdiutil detach $device -force
device=hdid testfloppy.img|cut -d ' ' -f 1
path=mount |grep -w '$device' | cut -d ' ' -f 3- | cut -d '(' -f 1

cp TEST.SYS $path/

hdiutil detach $device
```

However when running this code I get the following console code:

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=512 count=2880 of=testfloppy.img
2880+0 records in
2880+0 records out
1474560 bytes transferred in 0.004152 secs (355139415 bytes/sec)
device=$(hdid -nomount testfloppy.img)
echo evice
evice
newfs_msdos -F 12 evice
newfs_msdos: /dev/evice: No such file or directory
make: *** [All] Error 1
```

I tried using the backward ticks and I have also tried making it a string with the $$() part but neither of those have helped at all.

Comment: Try `echo $$device` (you have to escape shell variables with an additional `$`).  That also goes for other references to `$device` and `$path`  (that `'$device'` looks wrong as the single quote will stop variable expansion).

Comment: @trojanfoe I have made all my variables with $$ now, but on the echo line it now does not echo anything and any comments using $$device do not receive anything where a string should go.

Comment: @trojanfoe do you see anything wrong with this line? `path=$(mount |grep -w '$device' | cut -d ' ' -f 3- | cut -d '(' -f 1)` I have moved the code to a .sh for testing and it can go to this line.

Comment: Sounds like there is something wrong with the commands themselves.  As you say, test this using a shell script first before putting it into a `Makefile` (better still, just call the shell script from the `Makefile`).

Comment: Every line in a makefile recipe is run in a separate shell invocation. So your `device=...` invocation sets `device` in the shell in which it is run (e.g. `sh -c 'device=...'`) which then exits, rendering your `device` variable non-existent. Then when the next line is run (e.g. `sh -c 'echo $device'`), `device` is no longer set, with the end result that an empty line gets printed. And so on... You need to put the entire script on one line, with appropriate semicolons, escaping, etc... Or put the entire thing in an actual script, and have your makefile call that script.

Comment: @twalberg I think I'm going to make the Makefile execute an .sh script, it seems to be the easiest way until I actually need the Makefile to do stuff

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight difference between how you use variable in shell script and how you use variable in a Makefile.

Ex:

```
   var=10
   echo $var      #Works well in shell script
   echo $(var)    #Works well in Makefile
   echo ${var}    #Works well in Makefile
```

Try below makefile

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=512 count=2880 of=testfloppy.img
device=hdid -nomount testfloppy.img
echo ${device}
newfs_msdos -F 12 ${device}
hdiutil detach ${device} -force
device=hdid testfloppy.img|cut -d ' ' -f 1
path=mount |grep -w '${device}' | cut -d ' ' -f 3- | cut -d '(' -f 1

cp TEST.SYS ${path}/

hdiutil detach ${device}
```